# How to create an unknown number of Swing components?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I need to display a user-inputted number of tabs (`JTabbedPane`) (with the same initial content, but the ability to individually change the content), is there a way to create these components procedurally so I don't have to know how many there will be before the user input?

Comment: You can create an array of JTabbedPanes with the length being the user input, and initialize them with a for loop.

Comment: How are you creating your GUI for the moment ? Because you still have the hand on the instance to add, remove, or do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of change number of tabse depended on user input:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class TabbedPaneTest3 implements Runnable {

    private final JTabbedPane tabber = new JTabbedPane();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TabbedPaneTest3());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(3, 1, 10, 1));
        spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                Object val = spinner.getValue();
                if (val instanceof Number) {
                    updateTabsNumber((Number) val);
                }
            }
        });
        updateTabsNumber(3);
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Tab Pane");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Number of tabs: "));
        panel.add(spinner);
        frm.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frm.add(tabber);
        frm.setSize(600, 400);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void updateTabsNumber(Number val) {
        int count = val.intValue();
        tabber.removeAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            String text = "Tab " + (i + 1);
            JTextArea area = new JTextArea(10, 30);
            area.setText("Initial text for tab: " + (i + 1));
            tabber.addTab(text, new JScrollPane(area));
        }

    }
}
```